# Exception File Handling in a better way

Tags: c#, exception

I have this code for saving to a file.

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "ConnectFour.txt");

try
{       
using (StreamWriter myFile = File.CreateText(filePath))
{
  // saving code
}

}catch (IOException){
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error saving this game!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

} catch (Exception){
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error saving this game!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}
```

Is there a better way to handle exceptions when using file handling? maybe catch more specific exceptions like FileNotFound? What do you recommend? I'm asking this since when I am using my executable file for my application on another computer, I am getting the message box (an exception is being caught) and I can't know what it is! Also this exception isn't showing on each computer I have this application so it's more difficult to figure out!

Comment: Are you employing any kind of logging that provides a log file with full exception/stack trace information? Something like Log4Net?

Comment: @Chris Sinclair no I'm not using any logging

Comment: If you define a variable for each exception type, you get access to the message; for an IOException, that message will indicate the exact nature of the problem (such as an expected file not existing, corrupted file, device failure, etc). In addition, IOException is the base class for exceptions of more specific types, which you can catch and handle differently. Lastly, I would specifically catch SecurityExceptions as well; these are thrown when the user doesn't have the proper file permissions to do whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: @studentProgrammer: I would definitely look into implementing it, especially if you're trying to debug failures on multiple machines. Make sure that any unhandled exceptions in your application log full information out and you'll usually see exactly why. So for example, in this case, you might see a `FileNotFoundException` or a `PathTooLongException` or a `DirectoryNotFoundException` (all `IOExceptions` btw) without having to specifically catch all of them. Really, it covers the _exceptional_ cases that you had not accounted for and gives you information critical to debugging it.

Comment: @KeithS Yes it's a good idea to catch security exceptions, thanks! Do you think that in my case, (since I am saving into the temp folder of the computer the application is working on), this could be a security issue? Chris I think I'm going to use logging if I have the chance of reading on them, since I only used them once and I had no idea what I was doing! I'll research a bit on logging. I think it's worth it! Thanks!

Comment: @studentProgrammer Chris is right, you should add logging to your game. Also note that sometimes showing a detailed message to the user can create a security vulnerability. In this case, the message could be logged in an encrypted file that only you can decrypt and read. Of course this makes troubleshooting harder but sometimes it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the exception that is thrown and show the Message:

```
}
catch( IOException e )
{
   MessageBox.Show("There was an error saving this game: " + e.Message
                    , "ERROR"
                    , MessageBoxButtons.OK
                    , MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
                    , MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}
```

And if the file must exist before your operation you could do a `File.Exists( file )` .
Error checking is always prefered to exception handling...

Comment: hmm good idea to show the message yeah! But since I am using .CreateText() do I need to check for existence of the file as well?

Comment: I do it as a matter of style, but if it does not exist, an exception is thrown anyway...

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you usually should not catch every exception (by writing `catch(Exception)`), but only those, that you can really handle at this particular point.

Take a look at the documentation and see which exceptions can be thrown by all methods used in your saving code. Think about what they really mean in case of your specific algorithm and how you could translate the exceptions into user-friendly error messages.

For example, UnauthorizedAccessException and FileNotFoundException are very different things. The user does not understand what's wrong if you just write "An error occured".

Consider logging exceptions to get useful debugging information.

Comment: from where do I see the documentation of my project in visual studio?

Comment: @studentProgrammer You should be able to hit F1 while the cursor is on the function in question to see the documentation on it.  [File.CreateText MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
try{}

catch(exception ex){
if(ex is IOException){
messagebox.show("Your Specific Message");
//and do others like this

}
}
```

Comment: IOException hides a lot of different error reasons, what error did really occur? See my post for what I mean!

Answer (score 0):

The exception based workflow management is a suggested guideline, if not the only possible, in case of dealing with `IO` operations, so files too. Very often there is no other way to handle your program workflow, if not by **expected** exceptions handling when you're dealing with IO artifacts.

In your case, I would add `catch` on all *expected* exceptions, and for others just will leave to go up to the stack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if the file must exist prior to an operation I would alway do a File.Exists(...)...

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon That's can be worthwhile, but still introduces a race condition whereby _after_ the `File.Exists` call but _before_ the file opening, the file is removed by whatever process. Hence the caught exceptions are the only sure-fire way of knowing what's going on. Sometimes depending on your context, this is OK to do a `File.Exists` and assume that the file won't be modified before your subsequent read, but not always.

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon: depends how program works, it's much easier and clearer just manage it inside simple `try/catch`..